# Issue with testing ui interaction using selenium

Tags: html, ruby, unit-testing, selenium

I'm working on issue unit testing UI interaction using Selenium via Ruby using Selenium's Ruby Bindinds and Test::Unit. Its been successful for the most part but I've run in to a test case I can't get to work. What I need to do is wait for the table to load on the page then loop through and click on table headers with the class of `sorting`, recording the first row of the table and comparing it to the first row post click. Skipping headers without the `sorting` class and determining if all the sortable headers work in the browser.

Now the problem. The test fails the `assert_nothing_raised` test from Selenium timing out. Where? I don't know. It references `[test_cases/tc_commodities.rb:6]` but line 6 is `assert_nothing_raised do`. Since the test starts with that, not much information. I then started to narrow it down in my code by removing code. The issue is in the `columns.each` loop which means the `wait.until` block. That doesn't make sense because I can see the headers displayed on the page during the duration of the timeout. Page closes, test fails. I ran the test again, halted the execution and looked at the DOM. All the correct elements were there and being displayed. The script had plenty of time to pick them up. To be sure I put in a `sleep 15`. Still timed out waiting for the headers to display.

1. Why is this timing out? I've never had an issue with a displayed item on the page not returning true for .displayed?
2. Is this the best approach for this test case? Can anyone suggest a better solution?

**Failing Test Output**

```
$ ruby test_cases/tc_commodities.rb
Run options:

# Running tests:

Column Found
F

Finished tests in 46.652411s, 0.0214 tests/s, 0.0214 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test__sort_columns_on_stories_table(TestCommodities) [test_cases/tc_commodities.
rb:6]:
Exception raised:
<#<Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError: timed out after 10 seconds>>.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

**Selenium code**

```
def test__sort_columns_on_stories_table
    assert_nothing_raised do
        @browser.get 'some url'
        @wait.until do
            @browser.find_element(:css, "#dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(2)").displayed?
        end

        columns = @browser.find_elements(:css, "#dataTable thead th.sorting")

        columns.each do |column|
            puts "Column Found"

            @wait.until do
                column.displayed?                   
            end

            puts "Column Displayed"

            first_story_before = @browser.find_element(:css, "#dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(1)").attribute('id')
            column.click
            first_story_after = @browser.find_element(:css, "#dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(1)").attribute('id')

            assert_not_equal(first_story_after, first_story_before)
        end
    end
end
```

**Edit**

I'm using Chrome and Firefox Web Drivers. Same issue with both. I can remove the `wait.until` for the `column.displayed?` but then it throws an error that its not displayed on the page when it clearly is.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the similar issue as TimeTime out exception waiting for the page to load. But the page is fully loaded.

Which browser you are using? if its IE, what is the version of IEDriverServer?

Comment: Can you tell me which browser you are using? If its IE, Which version of IEDriverServer?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Firefox Web Drivers. Same issue with both. I can remove the `wait.until` for the `column.displayed?` but when it throws an error that its not displayed on the page when it clearly is.